# How to draw tangent lines of equal length at three equidistant points on a curved path?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tangent

like the bend triangle below

[image: The bend triangle]

And the MWE is all I can draw.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (4.5,0) -- (6,2) -- (1.5,2) -- cycle;
        \draw [xshift=3cm,yshift=1cm] (0,0) ellipse (1.2 and .6);
        \draw [xshift=3cm,yshift=1cm,->,teal] (0,.6) -- (.6,.6);
        \draw [xshift=3cm,yshift=1cm,->,teal] (1.2,0) -- (1.9,0);
        \draw [xshift=3cm,yshift=1cm,->,teal] (0,-.6) -- (.6,-.6);
        \draw [xshift=3cm,yshift=1cm,->,teal] ({-1.2*cos(30)},{-.6*sin(30)}) --++ (.6,0) node [above] {$v^a$};
        \draw [xshift=3cm,yshift=1cm,->,teal] ({-1.2*cos(30)},{.6*sin(30)}) --++ (.6,0);
        \shade [xshift=3cm,yshift=1cm,ball color=teal] (-1.2,0) circle (.06);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Your MWE won't compile because it's missing \begin{document} and \end{document}.  If you put those in, you'll see you get a 2-D image, not a 3-D image of the sort you want to create.  One way you could do it would be to draw the image using the tikz-3dplot and use pgf math to calculate the tangent points and lines.  It's not trivial, but it's feasible.